# How to get default texture in pro builder?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey there I'm using unity 2018.4.31f1. I just downloaded Pro Builder and I saw some tutorials but when I create an object using Pro Builder it doesn't give me that default material. Instead give me a simple black material why this happens so...I haven't changed anything. Everything is just default...

I'm getting this cube after build:
[This is the link of image I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weiuo.png)

I want this type of cube to be formed:
[This is the image I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF6KL.png)

Is there anything I had done wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Probuilder Preferences](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/manual/preferences.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20ProBuilder%20uses%20the%20ProBuilderDefault%20Material%20when%20creating%20new%20Meshes.) window in [Mesh Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/manual/preferences.html#settings) section, you can change **Material** Property. That will be default value. Or you can just use **Reset** button which in the same section(**Mesh Settings**).